# flood fill code acting strangely

Tags: javascript, canvas

I wrote some code which will work like this:

- grab the clicked point using variables x and y via e.layerX/y.
- x value will be reduced by one and check if the canvas color is black or not.
- if black it will stop otherwise continue.

The code I made should fill a single green line, but strangely it is filling the whole circle. It also covers up some of the black outline of my circle. Why is it so? How can I fix this?

Flood Fill Code:

canvas.addEventListener('click', fillit, false);

```
function fillit(e) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x = e.layerX;
    var y = e.layerY;

    for (;;) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        ctx.fill();
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
        if (imageData.data[0] == 0 && imageData.data[1] == 0 && imageData.data[2] == 0) {
            break;
        }
        x = x - 1;
    }
}
```

Full Code:

css :

```
    #mycircle{position:fixed;top:600px;left:0px;}
    #vanishmycircle{position:fixed;top:600px;left:100px;}
```

html :

```
    <form>
        <input id="mycircle" type="button" value="make a circle"> <input id=
        "vanishmycircle" type="button" value="delete a circle">
    </form>
```

javascript :

```
function makeit() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var atts = document.createAttribute('style');
    canvas.height = 400;
    canvas.width = 400;

    atts.value = "border:1px solid black;";
    canvas.setAttributeNode(atts);

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    document.getElementById('mycircle').addEventListener('click', acircle, false);
    document.getElementById('vanishmycircle').addEventListener('click', notacircle, false);

    function acircle(event) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.arc(150, 150, 125, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function notacircle(event) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('click', fillit, false);

    function fillit(e) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var x = e.layerX;
        var y = e.layerY;

        for (;;) {

            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            ctx.fill();
            var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
            if (imageData.data[0] == 0 && imageData.data[1] == 0 && imageData.data[2] == 0) {
                break;
            }
            x = x - 1;
        }
    }
}
window.onload = makeit;
```

Comment: ouch ! for(;;) is itching a bit ! use rather :  do { ...;  } while (condition);   Also, just retrieve just once the ctx after retrieving the canvas, and have a function that handles the mouse, then call a fill function that expect (x,y). (refactoring is a way of debugging)

Answer (score 0):

- Call `ctx.beginPath()` before drawing the green pixel to reset the path. Without this call the path of the circle would also get filled with green.
- When checking if the pixel is black you need to look at the *next* pixel, not the one that has just been painted. Use

  ```
  var imageData=ctx.getImageData(x-1,y,1,1);
  ```

  or move the decrement operation to before this call.
- When testing the colour, you must also check that the alpha (`imageData.data[3]`) is 255.
- I suggest you terminate the loop if `x` goes off the screen in case no black pixel is encountered.